# Что такое цифровая информация. Или, что означает 0 и 1 при записи информации на CD?

Tags: хранение-данных, пк, cd

Добрый вечер. И вновь я вынужден обратиться к Вашей помощи. В вузе мне задали написать реферат на тему: "CD-диск. История и хранение данных". Я учёл все аспекты , связанные с историей, хранением и записью информации на компакт-диск.Но хочу узнать от Вас - что означает 0 и 1 при записи данных на CD-диск?
Заранее благодарю за ответ...

Comment: зависит видимо от того, что именно на диск записывается.

Comment: знакомы понятия бит, байт, килобайт, мегабайт и т.д.???

Comment: Да. 
А 0 и 1 значат то же, что и на компьютере?
Т.е. есть электричество - нет электричества?

Comment: Или всё гораздо сложнее?

Comment: >А 0 и 1 значат то же, что и на компьютере? Т.е. есть электричество - нет электричества?

это вот шутка или реально вопрос?

Comment: на диске - это темный-светлый участок  - в одном случае лазер имел больше мощность, в другом меньше. Когда что - не принципиально. Это проблемы привода.

Там ещё до кодов Рида-Соломона дойдете:)

Comment: А 0 и 1 значат то же, что и на компьютере? Т.е. есть электричество - нет электричества?

Автор, не издевайтесь над чужими мозгами, они же живые!

Comment: Очень советую почитать книгу "Код" Чарльза Петцольда, все станет намного понятней.

Answer (score 3):

Давайте разберёмся, как кодируется информация. Она на привычных нам компьютерах кодируется при помощи *чисел*.

Например, как можно закодировать картинку? Очень просто! Делим картинку на отдельные точки. Для каждой точки, записываем её цвет в виде числа (например, частоту). [Скажем в скобках, что на самом деле кодируют немного по-другому, но это детали.] Теперь последовательность этих чисел и задаёт всю картинку.

Как закодировать текст? Тоже просто: люди договорились обозначать буквы числами (например, А = 1, Б = 2 и т. д.; снова-таки, на самом деле всё немного сложнее), так что вместо последовательности букв можно записывать последовательность чисел.

Так же кодируется числами и другая информация.

Теперь, как закодировать сами числа? Помогает двоичная запись этих чисел. Например, число 13 представляется в двоичной записи как 00001101 -- только единички и нолики. Значит, если мы сможем записать единички и нолики, мы сможем записать таким образом числа.

Как именно единички и нолики представляются на носителях информации -- внутренняя проблема самого носителя. На магнитных дисках это направление намагниченности магнитных доменов, на CD -- разная отражающая способность разных участков. Главное -- чтобы обслуживающее носитель железо смогло отличить нолик от единички.

Не правда ли, интересно устроены компьютеры?

Comment: Спасибо. Очень познавательно и информативно:)

Comment: @prog: пожалуйста!

Comment: @artyom_phpprogrammer, грубо говоря CD-диск это _высокотехнологичная_ грампластинка ))

Answer (score 0):

Лазер светит на дорожку под углом. с другой стороны под углом стоит приёмник. Далее если вызжена ямочка в диске и сигнал не считался, то значит это одно состояние (например 1) если сигнал считался и ямочка не вызжена, то другое состояние (в нашем случае 0)